# How can I handle errors with https.get in Node.js and prevent app from crashing?

Tags: node.js, api, asynchronous

I am working with Node.js for the first time and I am using the [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/api) API. I have created an Express app and I am able to upload a file, and then send it to the API. I then wait for a response from the CloudConvert API and process the response and download the converted file.

Currently, the file is downloaded immediately, but when CloudConvert hits the callback it crashes because of `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_DOMAIN_NAME]: Unable to determine the domain name`.

How could I set up these https.get calls so that they handle the errors?

```
router.get('/cloud-callback', function(req, res) {
  let request = https.get(`https:${req.query.url}`, function(response) {
    console.log("got response:" + response.statusCode);
    response.on("data", function(data) {
    let resData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
    let fileUrl = `https:${resData.output.url}`;
    let file = fs.createWriteStream("./data/rtfs/sample.rtf");

    let ccRequest = https.get(fileUrl, function(ccResponse) {
      ccResponse.pipe(file);
      }).on('error', (error) => console.log(error.message));;
    }).on('error', (error) => console.log(error.message));
  });
});


router.post('/convert2RTF/:filename', function(req, res) {
  const file = __basedir + "/data/" + req.params.filename + ".pdf";
  console.log("hi", file);
  cloudconvert.convert({
    "inputformat": "pdf",
    "outputformat": "rtf",
    "input": "download",
    "save": false,
    "file": "https://z620a87c.ngrok.io/sample.pdf",
    "callback": "https://z620a87c.ngrok.io/files/cloud-callback"
  });
  res.redirect(301,'/files');
});
```

Comment: `request.on('error', console.log)`?

Comment: I’m not sure why your existing error listeners aren’t doing the job, but it probably depends on what is happening that causes the error. For example, if it’s a timeout you have to listen to the timeout event rather than the error event.  Can you provide more details?  Also, most folks find the request module on npm much more Dev friendly than the raw http(s) module’s from node core.